# How to prevent Users in Domain installing and removing software?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, domain-controller

I am using ADDS in my Company, using Windows server 2012 r2.

Like the tittle, how to prevent instaling, removing any software for my users in their computer? I want to protect company's computers.

I dont want my users can installing , and removing anything.

So what can I do with GPO, what GPO can do that ?

Tks all.

Comment: Tell them not to. If they don't listen, give them a warning. If they still don't listen, fire them.

Comment: No, I just want to GPO to do this, not by telling

Comment: Don't make them local Administrators of their computers and they shouldn't be able to install software.

Comment: So just create a normal user and dont need to create any GPO for this case ?

Answer (score 0):

Well you just have to have UAC enabled and not to place them in any local administrator account group this way every time they need to install something or uninstall it will prompt them for a domain or local admin account .